# Is there a way to have a dual WP feed (full/partial)?

Tags: feed

Is there a way to have a dual WP feed?

We'd like a full feed for *one* particular subscriber and a partial feed for everybody else.

Is that possible??

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many feeds as you want, you basically create a valid feed in a custom template file using native WordPress functions. You can then restrict this feed by IP, username or role ( it's not clear on how you're doing this).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds